# Using of session can logged in directly without matching email & password in PHP

Tags: php, session, authentication

I am new in PHP, while I am trying to create log in page it can work fine until I added session, after use of session its logged in without check email & password. when I remove session its work fine, so I guess my sql query is right.
here is my PHP code:

```
     <?php
      session_start();
      include 'conn.php';
      if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
      $email=$_POST['email'];
     $password=$_POST['password'];
     $abc="SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email' && password='$password'";
     $res=mysqli_query($db,$abc);
    //  $test=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
    //  $name=$test['name'];
    if($res)
     {
      //$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
      //$_SESSION['name'] = $name;
       header('location:userprofile.php');
     }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Try `$res->num_rows > 0`

Comment: If your user logged in and already maintaining session then why your showing login page

Comment: @suraj if I remove the comment of session anyone can logged in my site(its like:no needed of email or password)

Comment: @Lublaut its working now, thanks!

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Please do not use this code in production unless you wish to invite the hacking of your customer's login credentials.

Comment: @JayBlanchard yeah sure! thanks for tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check for the number of rows:

```
$res->num_rows > 0
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.